# Apache POI XWPF - Check if a run contains a picture

Tags: java, xpath, apache-poi, xmlbeans, xwpf

My goal is to process a **.docx** document in Java, using Apache POI. I want to extract everything from the document to create a new one, but only with specific content, that I can choose from the processed document.
That works so far for tables and text, but I have a Problem regarding pictures. Normally I would extract them like this:

```
List<XWPFPictureData> images = r.getEmbeddedPictures();
```

Where **r** is extracted from a paragraph and is of type `XWPFRun`.
The big problem here is, that this solution only works for some images, it depends on how the image is inserted in the word document.

I can access the xml code of a run and tried to find images like this, that worked fine in python where you can state a xpath query.
I tried the same in Java but got an error message.

Here is my code to check if a run contains an image:

```
r.getCTR().selectPath(".//w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/pic:pic/pic:blipFill/a:blip/@r:embed"))
```

And it returns this Exception:
[image]

Comment: It seems that there is no XPath engine avalaible. Did you check your classpath

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the case. Adding the xmlbeans-xpath.jar to my project solved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the available engines are namespace aware ones. So the namespaces must be declared.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;

public class WordRunSelectPath {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordInsertPictures.docx"));
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
   for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
    String declareNameSpaces =   "declare namespace w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'; " 
                       + "declare namespace wp='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing'; "
                       + "declare namespace a='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'; "
                       + "declare namespace pic='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture'; "
                       + "declare namespace r='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships' ";

    XmlObject[] selectedObjects = run.getCTR().selectPath(
                         declareNameSpaces 
                       + ".//w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/pic:pic/pic:blipFill/a:blip/@r:embed");
    if (selectedObjects.length > 0) {
     String rID = selectedObjects[0].newCursor().getTextValue();
     System.out.println(rID);
    }
   }
  }

  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. The undeclared namespaces where my next problem, after solving the missing dependencies issue.

Comment: @Phil: You are welcome. I was positively surprised that someone knows how to use XPATH at all. Even when this one is "Disciple of the Great Serpent" aka Python ;-).